# why does text appear at the bottom

Tags: html, css

Why does "Some Text" appear at the bottom of the ul and not at the top?

```css
div{
display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div>
<p> Some text</p>
</div>
<div>
<ul>
  <li>This photo is amazing</li>
  <li>Great view!</li>
  <li>But why are the bullet points in the photo??</li>
  <li>Good question, indeed!</li>
</ul></div>
```

Comment: @RolandStarke no, because the default alignment is baseline

Comment: because thats how `inline-block` works- it will set inline with the natural flow of text (on the "baseline") [ref](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/d/display/#inline-block).